# How do I deploy djnago1.7 on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: django-1.7, pythonanywhere

i have done a project in django1.7 and python 2.7 [Git Hub Repo](https://github.com/pcakhilnadh/z)

i have cloned in Pythonanywhere

How do i properly configure it to run successfully ?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: this help page on our site should help you out: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango